# Simple chess function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, filter

My homework is to write simple functions related to chess. The `rook` function is working fine i guess it shows where can you step from the given start coordinate. And now I'm stuck with the `knight` function. My idea is to filter the coordinates list by the following condition: If the abs value of the coordinate differences is 3 and the rows are different then its a valid step. But I don't really know how should i implement this in Haskell. Any idea how should i do that?

My Code:

```
import Data.List

possibleMoves = [ (x, y) | x <- [0..7], y <- [7,6..0]]

rook :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)]
rook (x,y) = filter (/=(x,y)) (filter ((==y).snd) possibleMoves ++ filter ((==x).fst ) possibleMoves)

knight :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)] 
knight (x,y) = filter ((==3)((abs(y - head(map snd(possibleMoves))))).snd) possibleMoves
```

Resulting the following error :

```
    * Couldn't match expected type `Int -> Bool'
                  with actual type `Bool'
    * Possible cause: `== 3' is applied to too many arguments
      In the first argument of `(.)', namely
        `(== 3) ((abs (y - head (map snd (possibleMoves)))))'
      In the first argument of `filter', namely
        `((== 3) ((abs (y - head (map snd (possibleMoves))))) . snd)'
      In the expression:
        filter
          ((== 3) ((abs (y - head (map snd (possibleMoves))))) . snd)
          possibleMoves
  |
9 | knight (x,y) = filter ((==3)((abs(y - head(map snd(possibleMoves))))).snd) possibleMoves
  |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you written down the mathematical equation? Where is the problem?  In Haskell the absolute value function is `abs`, the difference function is `(-)` and you can accumulate the differences in row and column via `(+)`.  Finally you can determine if two rows are different via `(/=)`.  Can you stick those together?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson My problem is i don't know how should i filter by that abs value calculation function. My function looks like this now: ```knight (x,y) = filter (/=(x,y)) (filter (==3) (abs (x - fst(possibleMoves)))  possibleMoves)``` and i get a lot of type error.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comments. Saying "i get a lot of type error" is unhelpful. What are those errors. Include them above and not in the comment section.

Comment: You can find the problem, by examining the types of the pieces. Write your code in pieces, examine types and see if your types are matching what the compiler expects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're making it harder than it needs to be.

Given position `K` below, you could simply list each knight move:

```
    1   2   3   4   5
  +---+---+---+---+---+
1 |   | H |   | A |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
2 | G |   |   |   | B |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
3 |   |   | K |   |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
4 | F |   |   |   | C |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
5 |   | E |   | D |   |
  +---+---+---+---+---+
```

And remove the ones that are outside the chessboard.

```hs
knight :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)]
knight (x, y) = filter validPosition
  [ (x + 1, y + 2)
  , (x + 2, y + 1)
  , (x + 2, y - 1)
  , (x + 1, y - 2)
  , (x - 1, y - 2)
  , (x - 2, y - 1)
  , (x - 2, y + 1)
  , (x - 1, y + 2)
  ]
```

Then if you think you're repeating yourself too much:

```
knight' :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)]
knight' (x, y) = filter validPosition
  [ (x + dx, y + dy) | dx <- [-2,-1,1,2]
                     , dy <- [-2,-1,1,2]
                     , ... something about dx, dy and 3 ...
                     ]
```

It seems that the `(== y) . snd` stuff obscures the solution a little.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of filtering the knight's positions is actually really succinct and easy to implement using a list comprehension.

```
knight (x, y) = [(x', y') | x'<-[x-2..x+2], y'<-[y-2..y+2], abs (x' - x) + abs (y' - y) == 3 ]
```

Restricting the possible displacement values to -2 and +2 will also prevent the column and row from being the same, so you can do away with that condition.

The only thing is, it will also return values that are past the board. You could check this using your preexisting `possibleMoves` function:

```
import Data.List (intersect)
safeKnight = intersect possibleMoves . knight
```